# Elm find unused functions

Tags: static-analysis, elm

Let us for example have app like this:

```
port module MyApp exposing (main)

import Html.App as App

main =
  App.programWithFlags
    { init = init
    , view = view 
    , update = update 
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    }
```

Could we safely assume that only useful functions are the ones that are ports and anything that is called from `init`, `view`, `update` or `subscriptions`?

Because after some refactoring I stopped calling some function. Is any compiler flag or linter that could notify me that function could be safely removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only detect unused module imports while running [elm-make](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-make) with `--warn` flag.

That's all you could get from the compiler today.

Just remove stuff and compiler will tell you, if you have to put it back, I guess.

Comment: there's [a thread from january 2015 about elm and dead-code detection and tree-shaking](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.elm.general/9634) and basically it just needs someone to put in the time. at least we have the `--warn` flag available.